# Do you know how to prevent indexing of pages past the home page in WP?

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

I mean I don't want mysite.com/page/2, mysite.com/page/3 to be indexed.  This is because I use home.php for my theme, so that page/2, page/3 are all the same.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code in robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /$
Disallow: /
```

This will make sure that only home page is indexed and all other are disallowed.